# Connecting 3 monitors via HDMI

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, tv, dvi, displayport

I am trying to hook 3 tv's up to one computer all via HDMI. This setup has already been installed and I do not have the option to switch to a DVI connection or use VGA. I have this graphics card: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814131374, and when I bought it, it seemed like I could hook up the three TV's if I used the right combination of adapters. Now, when I tried hooking up 1 in DVI (either of them), 1 in HDMI and 1 in displayport (all with the right adapter to convert to HDMI) it didn't work. It could see the third monitor, but it was deactivated and would not let me activate it. I'm wondering if there is some other configuration that would work, and if not is there any way with any card to hook up the three monitors with HDMI? Is it possible that one of my adaptors (DVI to HDMI and DisplayPort to HDMI) was just not working correctly? Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

According to the [manual](http://www.power-color.com/Manual/090106/Radeon_HD_6800_Series_ENG.pdf) here are the available configurations
[image]
Now I don't see HDMIx3 listed, but I do not know if that means it is not supported. It does say DP to DVI needs a active adapter (I don't know if the same would go for DP to HDMI), that could be your problem. I would recommend re-reading the multiple display section of the manual that came with the card (chapter 4, page 11 on the online version), double check your DP to HDMI adapter is on the [compatible adapter list](http://support.amd.com/us/eyefinity/Pages/eyefinity-dongles.aspx), and make sure you have the latest eyefininty drivers.

Comment: Most EyeFinity cards require NATIVE Displayport (or an active adapter) for any monitors beyond the second.  This is exactly the problem, Scott, you're right.  (DVI and HDMI should be interchangeable for terms of this discussion - they both need a TDMS clock and the card only has two).